# 401 status handling with access and refresh Token React, Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt

I don't know how to handle 401 status request from my server, when access token is extinct.
I wrote accessTokenVerify on server side:

```
    require('dotenv').config();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

//  Access Token Verify
exports.accessTokenVerify = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.headers.authorization) return res.status(401).send({ msg: "Access Token is missing." })

    const BEARER = 'Bearer';
    const auth_token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    if (auth_token[0] !== BEARER) return res.status(401).send({ msg: "Access Token is not complete." })

    jwt.verify(auth_token[1], process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err) => {
        if (err) return res.status(401).send({ msg: "Access Token is invalid." })
        next();
    })
}
```

And I have refreshing access token endpoint localhost:5000/api/auth/refresh.
But I don't how to implement request on client side which send refresh request when I get 401 status response.

I have this so far:

```
const onSubmit = (values: Values) => {
 
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/posts", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
 
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: "Nazwa",
        text: "jakiś post",
        id: "341324132"
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status == 401) {
          refreshTokens();
          [and what next...]
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((resp) => console.log(resp))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

when refreshTokens() would be send resquest to /refresh endpoint and set new tokens, but I don't know how to resend primary request (adding post).

Comment: If you don't have any issues with using `async/await`, you can achieve it like `let resp = await fetch(...); if (resp.status === 401) { await refershTokens(); resp = await fetch(...); }`. (You can avoid duplication using recursion/retry by writing it in different function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just solved a similar situation myself lol. So for this, I would highly recommend managing your api requests through Axios. From there, you can use `axios interceptors` to parse both the response and error of a request, handle accordingly and retry the request by using `axios.request(error.config)`.